# Is AI capable of separating instruments from a track?

Tags: software, dj

At some point of my life I want to become a DJ (self-development).

I have in mind various approaches to it, both artistic and technical.

I'd like to ask on the latter, is it feasible as for 2022 to pick a track and separate the instruments in it using AI? If so, to what degree of audio quality can I aspire?

Comment: With that being said, the inability to cleanly remove the vocals out of pretty much any track is infamous.

Comment: Actually, legality aside, the once "Holy grail of the misinformed" is now quite possible. Separating a track into rough components - vocals, drums, bass, 'other' is now quite feasible. Izotope RX can do it, so can various online structures. Legally, you'd need to ask permission & pay an agreed royalty to use anything extracted this way [the details of which are quite beyond this stack's remit]..

Comment: Welcome! Please read a bit about [the questions that are on topic here](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and then use the "Edit" button to update the question. A question about exactly how to separate parts is good. Asking for specific software recommendations isn't covered here, and "give me all the advice about DJing that you can think of" is too broad. But feel free to open a separate question asking for more focused advice about specific musical aspects of DJing.

Comment: Why use AI? Karaoke music publishers either license the original tracks or have musicians re-perform them all the time and they make money doing it. There isn’t really any need or market for this in either the business or artistic senses.

Comment: thank you all for your suggestions, the question is now more aligned with the comunity subject

Comment: When you write "separate the instruments", do you mean "remove the vocals", or do you mean "separate each individual instrument into its own track"?

Comment: Does it have to be "AI" specifically, or is any computer software ok? How does one tell if a piece of software is "AI" or not, and why do you care? :)

Comment: @piiperiReinstateMonica - Software that receives a MIDI file composed of many instrument tracks can separate them without AI.  But an analogue audio signal would require some form of AI to separate it into instrument tracks.

Comment: @ElementsinSpace I can divide an audio signal to frequency components, it's called FFT. Is that AI? I can separate out frequencies from it, it's called a filter. Is that AI? I can find fundamental frequencies from audio, from peaks in the FFT output or from autocorrelation. Is that AI? Is digital signal processing AI? If a Hidden Markov Model is used, is that AI? If statistics are used, is that AI? If a probability model is used, is that AI? Is Antares Autotune AI? What is AI? Why is MIDI processing not AI? If it can calculate with nice certainty what they key of the tune is, isn't that AI?

Comment: I strongly suspect that the OP used "AI" to mean "an automated process whereby I can simply push a button and the computer works magic." In much the same way that an electric can opener is "AI." Yes, I think the OP's focus is on the output rather than the means, so if a simple EQ filter did the trick, I suspect that's what they're looking for. But the OP hasn't weighed in since they edited three days ago.

Comment: @piiperiReinstateMonica - I would say that all of those are a form of AI, because they are taking a mixed-up signal and processing it (in a language other than which it was composed) to hopefully arrived at a clean signal.  But splitting up a midi track into instrument parts is different, because the instruments' parts are not mixed up at all, they are stored as discreet channels already.

Comment: @ElementsinSpace I think, in a computing sense, "AI" is more narrowly defined as something relying on "machine learning"; I suspect the OP has misused it. And there's no indication from the OP that MIDI is part of the equation. But I think all this discussion is splitting hairs, and the question should be read as "Can I use a computer to separate instruments from a single mixed audio track, and how well can it be done," and if anyone has an answer (I don't) they should go ahead and give it.

Comment: @AndyBonner - I think of ML, as AI that is capable of changing the parameters and variables in the algorithms it is using, as it processes data. But I do agree that AI and ML aren't particularly relevant to the question. I think OP just wants to know if there is some computer software that can "somehow" separate an audio track into instrument parts.

Answer (score 2):

The **Stems** feature in **Serato DJ Pro 3 Beta** seems to offer what you're asking about.

Just yesterday youtube suggested I watch this video demonstrating the feature.

[Remixing Thriller with Serato Stems](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T_HYJUoqTbM)

Answer (score 2):

There's a lot of software out there that can pull out stems. If you're interested in the code aspect of it, [Spleeter](https://github.com/deezer/spleeter) is the place to start. It's used in iZotope's RX8, Unmix, VirtualDJ, and some other major pieces of commercial software, and you can also try it out on sites like [Vocali.se](https://vocali.se/) to test the quality (though if you work with the project yourself you can get better results than you would from a website). If you don't want to shell out money for software yet, I'd definitely recommend poking around with some of the open-source projects in that space (especially Spleeter) to see if what's out there already suits your needs — but lots of folks are already using this stuff to get stems for remixes and whatnot.

Comment: Update: FL Studio also now has stem-extraction built in, and I'm sure many more programs have come out with that feature, since it's incredibly valuable.

Answer (score 1):

Current technology seems to have reached the point where re-balancing a mix is possible - see the new version of 'Revolver'.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revolver:_Special_Edition

I don't think we can yet completely extract/remove instruments.   But it will doubtless come.  Maybe by actual analysis and isolation, maybe by artificial intelligence reconstruction of what it GUESSES was played.  Frightening things are being done with old photographs...